# In what order will the magnetic quantum number be filled

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

For example, the electron configuration for Cu(II) ion is [Ar]3d9. So only the 3d shell matters to the total orbital angular momentum of the ion. For 3d shell there are 5 possible values of $m_l : 0,\pm 1,\pm 2$. So how will the 9 electrons fill the 10 slots? What will the total orbital angular momentum $L$ be?

Comment: What you're looking for is [Aufbau's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle)!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, never mind. [Hund's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund's_rules) answers this directly.

Comment: So what is the answer? Will it be +/-2?